# php email in hotmail appears as plain text

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send a zip file via email with php.
Everything works with gmail and apple mail, but when I open the email with hotmail the code appears as plain text.
here's the code:

```
    <?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
        $count = 1;

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            /*make Image*/
            if($key == "mail")
            {
                continue;
            }
            $content = file_get_contents($_POST[$key]);
            $fp = fopen('SHRINK/image'.$count.'.jpg', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $content);
            $count++;
        }





        $fp2 = fopen("SHRINK/test.txt","w");
        fwrite($fp2,"COPYRIGHT - DOMINIK SCHATZ");

        //zip files
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open("SHRINK/SHRINK.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
        if ($res === TRUE)
        {
            $zip->addGlob("SHRINK/*");
        } else {
            echo 'Fehler beim erstellen der Zip-datei';
        }

        $zip->close();


        $myMail = "myMail@testmail.mymail";
        $name = "testname";
        $tel ="000000";
        $adr = "ADRESSE";


        $email = filter_var($_POST["mail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if(!$email)
        {
            echo json_encode("die emailadresse ist nicht gültig");
            exit();
        }

        //prepare zip for sending
        $fileatt_type = "application/zip"; // File Type
        $fileatt_name = 'SHRINK.zip'; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment
        $file = fopen("SHRINK/SHRINK.zip",'rb');
        $data = fread($file,filesize("SHRINK/SHRINK.zip"));
        fclose($file);

        //define headers and stuff
        $headers = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
        $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed\n" ;
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$myMail. "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: ".$name;
        $intro = "AUTOMATISCH GENERIERTE NACHRICHT<br><br>";

        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));


        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $message .= "<head></head><body>NAME: ".$name."<br>EMAIL: ".$myMail."<br>TELEFON: ".$tel."<br>
                    ADRESSE: ".$adr."<br>";
        $message .= "\r\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                    $data . "\n\n" .
                    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

        // string breaks after 60 chars
        $message = wordwrap($message, 60);
        $outro = "outro";



        //SEND EMAIL

        if(@mail($email, "Nachricht von ".$name, $intro.','.$message.','.$outro , $headers))
        {
            // Send
            $name = "SHRINK";

            //close
            fclose($fp);
            fclose($fp2);

            //delete packed filesize
            unlink('SHRINK/test.txt');
            unlink('SHRINK/SHRINK.zip');


            /*clear everything from tmp folder(just to be sure)*/
            $filesToDelete = $files = glob('SHRINK/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach($filesToDelete as $file){ // iterate files
              if(is_file($file))
                unlink($file); // delete file
            }

            echo json_encode("Ihr Bild wurde erfolgreich an ".$_POST["mail"]." versendet");
            exit();
        }
}

?>
```

Here's what I receive as email:

```
    AUTOMATISCH GENERIERTE NACHRICHT<br><br>,--==Multipart_Boundary_xa05228000753f946057d2d37ce1c2ea9x
Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<head></head><body>NAME: testname<br>EMAIL:
myMail@testmail.mymail<br>TELEFON: 000000<br>
                    ADRESSE: ADRESSE<br>
--==Multipart_Boundary_xa05228000753f946057d2d37ce1c2ea9x
Content-Type: application/zip;
 name="SHRINK.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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--==Multipart_Boundary_xa05228000753f946057d2d37ce1c2ea9x--
,outro
```

EDIT: I added the whole php-script

Comment: I'd just use something like phpmailer; this stuff is fiddly to roll yourself.

Comment: `the php code appears as plain text` why are you sending PHP code in email?

Comment: PHP-code should never have been sent in the mail so there must be something wrong with your script. Since you didn't include **the entire script** here we can't help you until you do. (If this is what you get by email the problem is probably just above this code)

Comment: I added the rest of the script.
It's not actually php-code, I'm sorry, there's plain html-code

Comment: There is no <?php at the beginning and there is no sendmail command in your script. So how is this script executed and where is the command to send the actual mail? And are you sure this **same** script works for sending mail to gMail and Apple mail?

Comment: I now added the current complete php script

Comment: I do see a problem on the line below `$mime_boundary =`. You close the `$mime_boundary =` line with `;` and on the next line you don't have any php but just a simple string. with "Content-Type". This doesn't seem to be a valid PHP-script. (It should generate an error on line 67, the one with "Content-Type"). What are you getting as output when calling this script? BTW. This script also **CAN'T** work for gMail or Apple mail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm currently working on the code too, and you're right, it didn't work. it's working for gmail now again- I edited the question

Comment: You still have a problem on line 76 (the one with `"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .`. The previous line (75) ended with `;` so line 76 is not valid PHP. So this script **STILL CAN'T** work with gmail and apple mail. (also remove the spaces before `<?php`). Aren't you getting any errors with this script ????

Comment: Maybe you should also add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your PHP to get the errors visible. Secondly... you're trying to send the mail twice. First with error-messages suppressed (i.e. @mail) and the second in the if statement. And third... your $name variable is not yet defined when reaching the first @mail statement which will always fail because of it.

Comment: I didn't try it recently width gmail, but it works fine in apple mail

Comment: Did you try adding `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top to see what's going wrong? And do you see the problem on line 76 of the code above (the `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n` line)?

Comment: I removed the ; on line76 and added "ini_set('display_errors', '1');". All I got were warnings of undefined variables (which I was aware of), but that's it. After fixing it, i don't get any warnings or errors, but it's still not working in outlook.(I edited the code on top). This is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` to your headers. The line you got now is not adding it to $headers (they are just "xxxx" lines now).

I suspect you want to do this:

```
 $semi_rand = md5(time());
 $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
 $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
 $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
```

Notice the `$header .=` before the "Content-Type....

You also might want to put some extra linebreaks (instead of `,`) between intro and outro:

```
if(@mail($email, "Nachricht von ".$name, $intro."\n".$message."\n".$outro , $headers))
```

After that your multiparts should be interpreted properly by any mail-client.

There is also a small problem if you're passing multiple images via POST. You do a $fp = fopen( in a loop but are not closing the previous one. So there are a lot of files open of which just the last one is in the $fp variable